# I can't change yarn to npm

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

Opened a ready-made project, IDEA asks you to run

```
yarn install
```

I already have npm installed, so I want to switch to it.
Deleted the yarn.lock file, package-lock.json, the node_modules folder. In the package file.json I don't have any mention of yarn.

Launched

```
npm install
```

The installation goes without errors, but after restarting the project IDEA still asks to run

```
yarn install
```

Where else can there be information about yarn? From where the same IDEA takes it.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/installing-and-removing-external-software-using-node-package-manager.html#ws_npm_yarn_configure_package_manager

Answer (score 0):

In the Settings/Preferences dialog (Ctrl+Alt+S), go to Languages and Frameworks -> Node.js. The Node.js page opens.
In the Package manager field, specify the package manager for your project.